# Missing the first letter on input field while using Selenium Webdriver (Java)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to fill out the phone number field (with a placeholder = "(__*) ***-****") using Selenium WebDriver. The issue I'm facing is: the driver does it very quickly and the first number is missing in 40% of my tests. I mean the number is 965-234-43 and what the driver does is 652 - 34 - 43_.

My code is:

```
private void setBankPhone(String bankPhone) {
    driver.findElement(bankPhoneField).click();
    driver.findElement(bankPhoneField).clear();
    driver.findElement(bankPhoneField).sendKeys(Keys.HOME + bankPhone);
    checkBankPhone(bankPhone);
}

private void checkBankPhone(String bankPhone){
    WebElement phonElement = driver.findElement(bankPhoneField);
    if (!phonElement.getAttribute("value").equals(bankPhone)) {
        setBankPhone(bankPhone);
    }
}
```

With `driver.findElement(bankPhoneField).sendKeys(bankPhone);` it's impossible to fill out the field at all.

Answer (score 0):

Though your code looks fine to me, I believe it's a latency/sync issue.

Can you try any of the below approaches before entering text to make sure readiness of the element?

**1. Wait for JavaScript to load**

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut);
JavascriptExecutor js_Executor = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();

ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jsLoad = driver -> js_Executor.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");
ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jQueryLoad = driver -> js_Executor.executeScript("return jQuery.active").toString().equals("0");

// Wait for JavaScript and jQuery to be loaded.
wait.until(jsLoad);
wait.until(jQueryLoad);
```

**2. Use wait conditions**

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webElement));
```

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, but it didn't resolve my issue.